# Is there a creature that is resistant or immune to damage from a non-magical source other than bludgeoning, slashing, and piercing?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, damage-resistance, damage-types, immunities

Reading this question: [Is there a distinction between magical damage and nonmagical damage?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/134341/is-there-a-distinction-between-magical-damage-and-nonmagical-damage)

I was wondering if there is a monster that is resistant or immune to damage from a non-magical source other than the common bludgeoning, piercing, and slashing damage. For example, this monster might resist fire damage only coming from a non-magical source, so using a torch would not be as effective as hurling a *fire bolt* at it.

**Is there an example of such a creature?**

Any damage resistance or immunity will do. If there is precedent or lore from an earlier edition that a creature has such a resistance/immunity, I would also welcome that information.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## There don't appear to be any official examples of this

You can filter a search on D&D Beyond for types of resistances/immunities and while you can filter for many very specific combinations of resistances/immunities, "nonmagical [damage type that is not BPS]" is not among them. Examples of some of the very specific filter combinations:

- Bludgeoning, Piercing, and Slashing from Nonmagical Attacks while in Dim Light or Darkness
- Piercing and Slashing from Nonmagical Attacks that aren't Adamantine
- Piercing and Slashing from Nonmagical Attacks that aren't Silvered
- Bludgeoning, Piercing, and Slashing from Nonmagical Attacks

The only options for resistances/immunities for other damage types appear to be a blanket resistance that covers all sources of that type of damage not just nonmagical sources.

For example the [air elemental](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/air-elemental) has

> **Damage Resistances** *Lightning, Thunder;* Bludgeoning, Piercing, and Slashing from Nonmagical Attacks

*emphasis mine*

This means that air elemental has resistance to lighting and thunder damage regardless of if the source is magical or not. Note also that the air elemental had a very low CR. The type of resistance/immunity would be a weaker form of the normal version and the we'd actually expect to see it more in lower CR creatures if at all, yet we don't.

While the D&D Beyond search is not necessarily perfect (those these filter options do appear to be all-inclusive in my shakedown) and it is impossible to prove a negative, this backs up my experience. I have seen many many monster stat blocks and I have never seen an example like you are looking for.

Thus I can state with reasonable confidence that there is no such monster present in official material.

Comment: "I have seen many many monster stat blocks and I have never seen an example like you are looking for." - I can attest to that from my own experience.