# What creatures/magic items have/can give resistance/immunity to nonmagical damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, monsters

In 5e, I'd like to know the ways in which a creature can have immunity to all types of nonmagical damage, either through a stat block or a magic item. Specifically, I'm looking for a complete list from the three core rulebooks of all creatures and magic items that are specifically able to resist all nonmagical damage, such as *Armor of Invulnerability*.

Comment: Related, [there *is* a distinction between magical and nonmagical damage](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/134341/62294).